# How to get li length by click span inside li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I attached an event on span element which is inside list so now it should return the length of LI. Can you find the error where i am wrong. I tried below code please check once

HTML Code

```
<ul>
    <li><span class="getLength">get</span> <a href="#">one</a></li>
    <li><span class="getLength">get</span> <a href="#">Two</a></li>
    <li><span class="getLength">get</span> <a href="#">Three</a></li>
    <li><span class="getLength">get</span> <a href="#">Four</a></li>
</ul>
```

JS Code

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('.getLength').click(function(){ alert('f');
        alert($(this).closest('ul').find('li').length());
    })
})
</script>
```

Comment: `TypeError: number is not a function`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.length` is a property, not a function. Use:

```
$(this).closest('ul').find('li').length;
```

Or you *could* (but shouldn't) use `.size()` {***version deprecated: 1.8***}

```
$(this).closest('ul').find('li').size();
```

Comment: Please dont suggest `.size()`. It was deprecated. Save your upvotes. :)

Comment: Thanks guys...honestly i did not know size was deprecated.

Comment: @RohitBatham: glad it helps rohit :)

Answer (score 1):

working fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/UVM9Q/

```
$(function(){
    $('.getLength').click(function(){ 
        alert($(this).closest('ul').find('li').length);
    })
})
```